# Softphone not connecting Asterisk

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, sip

I am trying to connect my X-Lite with a remote Asterisk server. I had installed that on a Ubuntu VPS server (14.04) following this tutorial: https://www.callcentric.com/support/device/asterisk/1_8
I had followed everything wrote on that article.

In sip.conf I changed like this:

```
[general]
dtmfmode = rfc2833
context=from-callcentric
srvlookup=yes
register => 1777MYCCID:SUPERSECRET@callcentric.com
session-timers=refuse

[callcentric]
type=peer
context=from-callcentric
host=callcentric.com
fromdomain=callcentric.com
defaultuser=1777MYCCID
fromuser=1777MYCCID
secret=SUPERSECRET
insecure=port,invite
disallowed_methods=UPDATE
directmedia=no
videosupport=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw

[123]
context=to-callcentric
type=friend
defaultuser=123
secret=PASSWORD
host=dynamic
```

In extensions.conf I added this line at bottom:

```
[from-callcentric]
exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/123)

[to-callcentric]
exten => _XX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@callcentric)
```

From terminal:

```
 asterisk -r

Privilege escalation protection disabled!
See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/x/1gKfAQ for more details.
Asterisk 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1, Copyright (C) 1999 - 2013 Digium, Inc. and others.
Created by Mark Spencer <markster@digium.com>
Asterisk comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; type 'core show warranty' for details.
This is free software, with components licensed under the GNU General Public
License version 2 and other licenses; you are welcome to redistribute it under
certain conditions. Type 'core show license' for details.
=========================================================================
Connected to Asterisk 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1 currently running on torrent (pid = 518)
torrent*CLI>

torrent*CLI> sip show registry
Host                                    dnsmgr Username       Refresh State                Reg.Time
callcentric.com:5060                    N      17772807810         45 Registered           Thu, 10 Sep 2015 11:00:55
1 SIP registrations.

torrent*CLI> sip show peers
Name/username             Host                                    Dyn Forcerport ACL Port     Status      Description
123/123                   (Unspecified)                            D   a             0        Unmonitored
callcentric/17772807810   204.11.192.163                               a             5080     Unmonitored
2 sip peers [Monitored: 0 online, 0 offline Unmonitored: 1 online, 1 offline]
```

but after connecting my softphone X-Lite with Asterisk using extension 123 I am getting this error: `SIP error 408`. I used following info:

```
User ID: 123
Pass: 123
Domain: My VPS IP
```

where I did mistake? Any suggestion please...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your public IP address of your server as the SIP proxy in the account settings in X-Lite. I'm not totally sure why this doesn't work without, but adding it worked for me connecting X-Lite to my Asterisk.